# Get value from custom attribute-decorated property?

Tags: c#, .net, custom-properties

I've written a custom attribute that I use on certain members of a class:

```
public class Dummy
{
    [MyAttribute]
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    [MyAttribute]
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}
```

I'm able to get the custom attributes from the type and find my specific attribute.  What I can't figure out how to do is to get the values of the assigned properties.  When I take an instance of Dummy and pass it (as an object) to my method, how can I take the PropertyInfo object I get back from .GetProperties() and get the values assigned to .Foo and .Bar?

EDIT:

My problem is that I can't figure out how to properly call GetValue.

```
void TestMethod (object o)
{
    Type t = o.GetType();

    var props = t.GetProperties();
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        var propattr = prop.GetCustomAttributes(false);

        object attr = (from row in propattr where row.GetType() == typeof(MyAttribute) select row).First();
        if (attr == null)
            continue;

        MyAttribute myattr = (MyAttribute)attr;

        var value = prop.GetValue(prop, null);
    }
}
```

However, when I do this, the prop.GetValue call gives me a TargetException - Object does not match target type.  How do I structure this call to get this value?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your need to pass object itself to GetValue, not a property object:

```
var value = prop.GetValue(o, null);
```

And one more thing - you should use not .First(), but .FirstOrDefault(), because your code will throw an exception, if some property does not contains any attributes:

```
object attr = (from row in propattr 
               where row.GetType() == typeof(MyAttribute) 
               select row)
              .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Agreed on FirstOrDefault -- this is mostly a contrived example to demonstrate the problem, but thanks for the help.  Duh, can't believe that was it.

Answer (score 3):

You get array of `PropertyInfo` using `.GetProperties()` and call [PropertyInfo.GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue.aspx) Method on each

Call it this way:

```
var value = prop.GetValue(o, null);
```

Comment: To clarify; the OP will need an instance of the Dummy class in order to get a property value from it. A Type by itself isn't enough.

Comment: I've updated my question -- my problem is exactly with .GetValue and how to call it so it actually works.